# How can I rewrite this list comprehension in Python?

Tags: python

maybe anyone of you knows how to write this code in other way in python:     `return [a for a,b in zip(s,previous_function(s)) if b]`

Comment: A common mistake with list comprehensions is trying to read them backwards e.g. in this case looking at `if b` first, then `for a,b in...` next. In fact list comprehensions should be read from left to right, with the exception of the expression at the very start. So this should be read as `for a,b in ...` first, then `if b`.

Answer (score 2):

This is the *list comprehension* equivalent to:

```
my_list = []
for a,b in zip(s,previous_function(s)):
    if b:
        my_list.append(a)
return my_list
```

Comment: @Kesha:  [Accept my answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if it helped, for others taking reference for the same problem in future. :-)